# What is this symbol on this video

Tags: 7.0-nougat

I recorded a video and cannot play it. It is close to 1GB in size and I used a huawei mate 9. Smaller sizes are fine.

[image: what happens when I try and play the video]
[image: The symbol]

Comment: install any other media player and check. (select media player that support different formats )

Comment: But the same app recording smaller video size can be played

Comment: Are you trying to play it on same phone on which you recorded it?

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading **VLC player** or **MX Player**.
If the video doesn't show up on these apps as well, the file might be corrupt.

Answer (score 0):

It may not playing because higher video **size** or **high** **resolution** of the video. Sometimes lesser **RAM** and **ROM** are unable to play **high resolution** videos(on **built** in media player). Try some other players available on store like **MX player** etc(**MX Player** would be a good option), or copy your video on **PC**, if its not even plays on **PC** then your file is **corrupt**.